# While randomly and not repeating twice

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
$answer = explode(" ", $row2['answer']);

foreach($tags as $i =>$key) {
$i >0;   
echo $i.' '.$key .'</br>';
}
```

the output is

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
4 e
5 f
```

I'd like that the output be random, but doesn't repeat twice.

For example:

```
e 4
a 0
c 2
f 5
d 3
b 1
```

Any idea please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why new account? This was just asked a few minutes ago on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314277 by: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5741276/mateus-gutemberg

Comment: was in the wrong section, sorry

Comment: Once a random number has been generated you must save it and compare any new random number to that list. If there is a match you have to re-run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of to achieve this would be to use the `shuffle` method on an array collection. This however does not guarantee non-sequentialness:

```
$range = range(1,5);
shuffle($range);
foreach($range as $int){
    echo $int;
}
```